# Understand how vector subset replacement works in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I'd like to understand what's going on in this piece of R code I was testing. I'd like to replace part of a vector with another vector. The `original` and `replacement` values are in a data.frame. I'd like to replace all elements of the vector that match the `original` column with the corresponding `replacement` values. I have the answer to the larger question, but I'm unable to understand how it works.

Here's a simple example:

```r
> vecA <- 1:5;
> vecB <- data.frame(orig=c(2,3), repl=c(22,33));
> vecA[vecA %in% vecB$orig] <- vecB$repl #Question-1
> vecA
[1]  1 22 33  4  5

> vecD<-data.frame(orig=c(5,7), repl=c(55,77))
> vecA[vecA %in% vecD$orig] <- vecD$repl #Question-2
Warning message:
In vecA[vecA %in% vecD$orig] <- vecD$repl :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> vecA
[1]  1 22 33  4 55
```

Here are my questions:

1. How does the assignment on Line-3 work? The LHS expression is a 2-item vector, whereas the RHS is a 5-element vector.
2. Why does the assignment on Line-6 give a warning (but still work)?

Comment: Just realized RHS is a 2-element vector too. I'm dumb.

Comment: this book https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf (chapter three) gives you a nice description of Vecterization in R. Check it out.

Comment: If the replacement vector is not the same length as the original, it will use as much of the vector as it needs. In your case, it only needs to replace one value so it just uses the first element of the vector. You can try and replace a longer vector with a shorter one too: `vecA[c(F,F,T,T,T)] <- c(20,30)` and it will use begin to repeat the replacement vector to fill the extra value. This is known as *vector recycling*.

Comment: I'd use `match()` instead, first example works by chance that vecA is 1 to 5 in sorted order, and dataframe is also ordered 2, 3. If vecA was 1,3,2,4,5, you would get unexpected results.

Comment: Is the `match` equivalent `vecA[match(vecB$orig, vecA)] <- vecB$repl`, thus ensuring `vecB` is processed in the same order across `orig` and `repl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The First Question**

R goes through each element in `vecA` and checks to see if it exists in `vecB$orig`. The `%in%` operator will return a boolean. If you run the command `vecA %in% vecB$orig` you get the following:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

which is telling you that in the vector `1 2 3 4 5` it sees `2` and `3` in `vecB$orig`.

By subsetting `vecA` by this command, you are isolating only the `TRUE` values in `vecA`, so `vecA[vecA %in% vecB$orig]` returns:

```
[1] 2 3
```

On the RHS, you are re-assigning wherever `vecA[vecA %in% vecB$orig]` equals `TRUE` to `vecB$repl`, which will replace `2 3` in `vecA` with `22 33`.

**The Second Question**

In this case, the same logic applies for subsetting, but running `vecA[vecA %in% vecD$orig]` gives you

```
[1] 5
```

as `7` does not exist in `vecA`. You are trying to replace a vector of length 1 with a vector of length 2, which is what triggers the warning. In this case, it will just replace the first element of `vecD$repl` which happens to be `55`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I realized a few minutes after I'd posted that my assumption about the RHS vector being of length 5 was the flaw in my thinking and what confused me.